# C++ - Reading table of numbers from file into 2D Array (only last row stored)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Starting with an input file that looks like this:

```
2 3
2 3 4
4 3 2
```

I am trying to read this data into a 2D array in C++ (the first row specifying number of rows / cols).

My code currently looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open ("dataset.in");

  // a matrix
  int a_numrows;
  int a_numcols;
  int a[a_numrows][a_numcols];

  fin >> a_numrows >> a_numcols;
  cout << a_numrows << " " << a_numcols << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<a_numrows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j<a_numcols; j++)
    {
      fin >> a[i][j];
    }
  }
  cout << a[0][0] << endl;

  fin.close();
  return 0;
}
```

However it seems as though in each row of the 2D array, the last row is being stored. Thus when `a[0][0]` is outputted, it returns `4`. This behavior is not how I think things should work coming from other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must permute these lines:

```
 int a[a_numrows][a_numcols];

 fin >> a_numrows >> a_numcols;
```

to

```
 fin >> a_numrows >> a_numcols;

 int a[a_numrows][a_numcols];
```

I guess this is a mistake of inattention.

---

That's said, there are safer/better ways to declare/use 2D arrays. Here is a possible example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream fin("dataset.in");

  size_t n_rows, n_cols;
  fin >> n_rows >> n_cols;

  using T = int;
  std::vector<T> array(n_rows * n_cols);
  array.assign(std::istream_iterator<T>(fin), std::istream_iterator<T>());

  fin.close();

  //-----

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n_cols; j++)
    {
      std::cout << array[i * n_cols + j] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ reader.cpp; ./a.out
2   3   4   
4   3   2
```

**Remember** that when doing numerical computations it is generally better to store all the numbers into a **contiguous memory chunk** (like it is done in `std::vector`). In this situation it is easier for the compiler to vectorize your code.

To access components use:

- `[i*n_cols+j]`: row-major (C-style) -> the given example,

  more efficient to loop in this order: `for i { for j ... } }`
- `[j*n_rows+i]`: column-major (Fortran-style) -> compatible with [Blas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) & [Lapack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK),

  more efficient to loop in this order `for j { for i ... } }`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I did that.  Just needed someone else to see it because I had been staring at these lines for the last 10-15 minutes extremely puzzled.  I'll accept this answer as soon as the time allows.  Thanks!

Comment: @orwinmc I have updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

To declare an array in C++, the size has to be known at compile time. I.e. you can't pass a_numrows and a_numcols as array-dimensions as these are runtime values. For such an approach I would use a std::vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> a;
//... read a_numrows and a_numcols
a.resize(a_numrows); //resize creates #a_numrows empty columns
for(int i = 0; i < a_numrows; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < a_numcols; ++j)
    {
        int value; fin >> value;
        a[i].push_back(value); //access the ith row and add a new column with value inside
    }
}
```